# Strange behavior of a int variable

Tags: c

I have wrote a C program that calculates the binary number of a decimal number, given in input, but I have a big problem caused by the variable used for keep the number given in input.

This is my code:

```
int main() {
    // variables declaration
    int n,a,i=0;
    int vector[i];
    float rest;
    // acquisition of the input number
    printf("enter an integer:...");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n>0) {
        // calculation and comparison of the data acquired to obtain the binary output
        rest=n%2;
        if (rest!= 0) {
            vector[i]=1;
        }
        else if (rest== 0) {
            vector[i]=0;
        }
        n=n/2;
        i++;
    }
    // representation of the binary value calculated
    printf("the binary value of the number entered is: ");
    for(a=i-1;a>=0;a--) {
        printf("%d",vector[a]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that if I put a input number greater or equal to 1024, the binary number will be wrong. So with the debug tool, I found that the problem is in the n variable, precisely in the `n=n/2` instruction.

If you put 1024 as input number, `n=n/2` works fine until the program reach the 4 value of n, and for that value the `n=n/2` instruction doesn't work, and gave 0 value to n.

So I'm stuck here and I don't know what kind of problem it is.

Comment: `int i=0; int vettore[i];` That will declare an empty array. (Which is illegal by the way) I guess you wanted `int vettore[32]` or something...

Comment: how big is `vettore` supposed to be? currently it hold no elements

Comment: `resto` should not be float

Comment: The fact is that, "Vettore" doesn't have a precisely dimension, because it must keep the values for the binary number, and "Vettore" may be of different size according with the binary number which derives from the number of input (n)

Comment: it doesn't automaticly resize itself. make it big enough, ie whatever is the bitsize of int on your platform

Comment: this line: int vector[i]; should be int vector[ sizeof int * 8];

Comment: The while() loop, the code could be much simpler, such as: while( int i=0; i < (sizeof int *8); i++ ) { vectore[i] = (n & (1 << i))? 1 : 0; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't went through whole code. But you declared `int i=0` and `int vettore[i];` But inside while loop you are incrementing `i` and modifying the `vettore[i]` which is dangerous and wrong. (EDIT)

You can try something like this.

`int vettore[i];`  --->  `int vettore[100];  // just to work in some cases binary upto length of 100 bits`

Comment: i know, this may be dangerous and wrong but i'm still a beginner, and i don't have the knowledge for do this in a safer way, because i don't know yet the possible problems that can appear, if i initialize a variable in this way

Comment: @Luca. No Problem :). why i said it is dangerous is because you were only declaring an array of size one . And trying to modify the content of it's subsequent memory location which you should not modify.

Comment: There's nothing particular dangerous about changing the value of `i` after defining `int vettore[i];`. The length of `vettore` is set when it's defined. Changing `i` later has no effect on it. What's dangerous is defining a zero-length array (variable-length or not) and attempting to modify its (nonexistent) elements.

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson I was also try to say the same but my language was not clear.

Answer (score 3):

```
int n,a,i=0;
int vettore[i];
```

`vettore` is a variable-length array. Its length is determined when it's defined. Changing the value of `i` later has no effect on `vettore`.

A zero-length array is invalid, but for a VLA it can't (necessarily) be diaghosed at compile time. Since `vettore` has no elements, trying to assign a value to any element is likely to clobber other variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much guys, i've done the suggested changes and everything works fine !!
The only things that i needed to do was initialize to 0 the variable i and to 100 the vector !

Comment: Please keep in mind array of dimension `100`can only store upto `100` bits.